# Lodash. How filter object of objects?

Tags: javascript, lodash

There object of carts with items.

```
carts: {
                0: {
                    id:1,
                    items:{
                        0:{id:100},
                        1:{id:101},
                        2:{id:10}
                    }
                },
                1: {
                    id:2,
                    items:{
                        0:{id:34},
                        1:{id:15},
                        2:{id:46}
                    }
                },
            }
```

Also i have simple array with items id [101, 46] to remove from first array.

How filter my object by lodash?

Comment: It's not an array, it's an object of objects

Comment: Yes, that is not an array. And how exactly do you want to filter? Show the result "array" as well.

Comment: fixed question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar solution to what Jonas proposed but with plain ES5, Lodash and without mutations:

```
var carts = {
    // ...
};

function getFilteredCarts(carts, idsToRemove) {
    return _.mapValues(carts, function (value) {
        return _.omitBy(value.items, function (item) {
            return _.includes(idsToRemove, item.id);
        });
    });
}

getFilteredCarts(carts, [101, 46]);
```

[Try it](https://codepen.io/drudv/pen/VrjZyE)

Answer (score 1):

```
Object.values(carts).forEach(({items}) => {
  for(var i in items)
    if(ids.includes(items[i].id)) delete items[i];
});
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##pVFBboMwELzzCouTLbkIUpoDUXrLOQ@IcjD20jpycGUbpAr57dQYeklpIrV7nJkd7cxeWM8sN/LDPbVawDhy3VqHODPOoj0aEnQzebUCTiNFVdB1xsHVVutbs@UwLee5p79qikVT3NFsFo1fVfxEV6yKO@k2/0n3XD4O9/IwW7n9Yza/S5L5s1JMfz2FJmm5PS@wVpAp/YbTGhptIKXx/zRtpHJgUP2Z0mmRBPmxvgB3Wc9UBxZHHcnC0oHxd4yH2IYnaP8aiwwE7plBEsl2borEu2SDg18mW646EXwidZLnTApCkAAFDtA3uEs8uT3UgO2UWw4N7Dh@AQ)

Comment: But, it make items undefined. How full remove items from object?

Comment: @ilya it does remove them. *undefined* is javascripts way of telling you that it was deleted

Comment: Yes, It's removed. But i need full destroy item. I tried change delete to splice and got error. (offset object)

Comment: @ilya to jse spli e you need an array. and i really think you should rethink your datastructure, itswell suited for arrays

Comment: I got it's data from api  ←→ database